# Ajax com PHP não está reconhecendo campo index do metodo POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou fazendo um sistema para pedidos de restaurantes, e tenho uma parte para dividir comanda.
Tenho um javascript para criar inputs das comandas que eu quero dividir, com tamanho maximo de 3 inputs de comanda

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var linha = 1;
    function addInput(divName) {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        if (linha < 4) {
            newdiv.innerHTML = 'Comanda [' + linha + ']';
            newdiv.innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="ncomanda[' + linha + ']" name="DividirComanda[]">';
            newdiv.innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="scomanda[' + linha + ']" name="SenhaComanda[]">';

            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
            linha++;
        }
    }




</script>
```

Mas preciso verificar o login e a senha da comanda que quero dividir utilizando AJAX.

Meu AJAX está assim

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function alterar_div() {
                for (var i = 0; i < linha ; i++){
                var nome_comanda = $('#ncomanda['+i+']').val();
                var senha_comanda = $('#scomanda['+i+']').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "verificaLogin.php",
                    data: {
                        nome_comanda: nome_comanda,
                        senha_comanda: senha_comanda
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#conteudo').html(data);
                    }
                });
                }
            }

</script>
```

E meu arquivo PHP verificaLogin.php, está assim:

```
 <?php
$nome_comanda = $_POST['nome_comanda'];
$senha_comana = $_POST['senha_comanda'];

include "../Functions/conecta_mysql.inc";
//query para verificacao se usuario e senha conferem
$query = "SELECT * FROM comanda "
        . "WHERE nr_comanda='$nome_comanda' and senha_comanda='$senha_comanda'; ";

$resultado = mysqli_query($con,$query);

//Lê o número de linhas, se igual a ZERO, 
//usuario nao cadastrado ou senha
//nao confere

$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($linhas == 0) {
    echo "Invalida";
} else {
    echo 'Ok';
}



?>
```

Porem, ao clicar no botão "verifica login" que irá chamar a função de AJAX, ele retorna esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notice: Undefined index: nome_comanda in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ComandaEletronica/Cliente/verificaLogin.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: senha_comanda in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ComandaEletronica/Cliente/verificaLogin.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined variable: senha_comanda in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ComandaEletronica/Cliente/verificaLogin.php on line 8

Porque não está reconhecendo a variavel index do metodo POST no arquivo verificaLogin ? O Ajax não está passando ?

Comment: E qual o resultado de `var_dump($_POST)`? Você verificou nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor, na aba Network, se a requisição AJAX foi feita corretamente?

Comment: O var_dump retorna array(0) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#ncomanda['+i+']').val();
$('#scomanda['+i+']').val();
```

Os códigos acima estão retornando "undefined", o que faz com que as variaveis não sejam enviadas para o PHP.

Verifique os seletores ;)